# The name 'button' does not exist in the current context MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am getting the title error on "button" on this line:

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action("defectsPartial", new { id = button})");
```

in my script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#myModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                var button = document.getElementById("button").value;
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("myPartial", new { id = button})");
            },
                buttons:{
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
        });
        $(".launch").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the function with the button:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="launch" value= "@item.Id" id="button">Go</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: you cannot use js variable in c# code

Answer (score 2):

**Javascipt** variable will not be accessible in razor.

do like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("defectsPartial")';
url = url+"?id="+button;
$(this).load(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `button` as a variable but it has to be string.

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("defectsPartial", new { id = "button"})');
```

Also I'm not sure is there such html element as `button`. Maybe you should use `<input type="button" />` ?.

Comment: There is a `button` element which allows more flexible formatting than `input type='button'`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that Url.Action gets evaluated at compilation of the razor view, but the button variable is javascript, which gets evaluated on the client.

You would have to add the id manually:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#myModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                var button = document.getElementById("button").value;
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("myPartial")" + button);
            },
            buttons:{
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $(".launch").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```